# C# Date formatting issue

Tags: c#, date

I have the following:

```
string QDI_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00.0000000K";            

string from = "2016-06-20T16:20:00.0000000-04:00";
string to =   "2016-06-21T16:21:00.0000000-04:00";

DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(from, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None).Date;
DateTime toDate =   DateTime.ParseExact(to, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None).Date;

Console.WriteLine(fromDate);
Console.WriteLine(toDate);
```

This prints out the Date without the hour and minutes. How do I make it work and show the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do just remove your ending ".Date" from your code.

```
string QDI_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00.0000000K";

string from = "2016-06-20T16:20:00.0000000-04:00";
string to = "2016-06-21T16:21:00.0000000-04:00";

DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(from, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(to, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

Console.WriteLine(fromDate);
Console.WriteLine(toDate);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `.Date`  you are selecting the date part only from the resulted DateTime object. So the default value for the time will be applied, Remove `.Date` then you will get the expected result;

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(from, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime toDate =   DateTime.ParseExact(to, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p8FTiy) will show you the difference

Answer (score 1):

You are calling .date which is selecting just the date part:

```
string from = "2016-06-20T16:20:00.0000000-04:00";
DateTime fromDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(from, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime toDateTime =   DateTime.ParseExact(to, QDI_DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Will produce:

```
> 6/20/2016 8:20:00 PM 
> 6/21/2016 8:21:00 PM
```

Notice the lack of .Date on the end